# SQL - Rank monthly dataset high, medium, low

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, rank, percentile

I have a table which includes the month, accountID and a set of application scores. I want to create a new column which either gives a 'high', 'medium' or 'low' for the top, middle and bottom 33% of the results each month.

If I use rank() I can order the application scores for a single month or the whole dataset but I'm unsure how to order it per month. Also, on my version of sql server percent_rank() does not work.

```
select 
    AccountID
,   ApplicationScore
,   rank() over (order by applicationscore asc) as Rank
from Table
```

I then know I need to put the rank() statement in a subquery and then use a case statement to apply the 'high', 'medium' or 'low'.

```
select 
    AccountID
,   case when rank <= total/3 then 'low'
         when rank > total/3 and rank <= (total/3)*2 then 'medium'
         when rank > (total/3)*2 then 'high' end ApplicationScore 
from (subquery) a
```

Comment: What is your expected output?  Do want ranks within each month, or over the entire data set?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want my table to say Month, AccountID, ApplicationScore, Rank. Rank is effectively MonthlyRank which gives a 'low' 'medium' or 'high' rank depending on if it is in the top, middle or bottom third of the results that month

Answer (score 1):

Ntile(3) worked very well

```
select 
    AccountID
,   Monthstart
,   ApplicationScore
,   ntile(3) over (partition by monthstart order by applicationscore) Rank  
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server may have something built in to handle your problem.  But we can easily use a ratio of counts to find the three segments of your scores, for each month.  The ratio we can use is the count, partitioned by month and ordered by score, divided by the count for the entire month.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
        1.0 * COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Month ORDER BY ApplicationScore) /
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Month) AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    AccountID,
    Month,
    ApplicationScore,
    CASE WHEN cnt < 0.34 THEN 'low'
         WHEN cnt < 0.67 THEN 'medium'
         ELSE 'high' END AS rank
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    Month,
    ApplicationScore DESC;
```

### Demo